# this.setState is not functioning within my "validate(e)" method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

Within my basic login app, I have isAuthorized as a boolean state declared within my constructor.

When my app renders the form's onSubmit section and executes the validate function, the setState does not set this.state.isAuthorized to the value of the declared authorized variable. Why is that? I googled everywhere and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your time

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/bootstrap.css'; // You can download @ getbootstrap.com
import '../css/main.css'; // located in the bottom as a comment

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "first":"John",
                    "last":"Doe",
                    "email":"johnee23@email.com"
                },
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "first":"Alexander",
                    "last":"Richards",
                    "email":"alexthegreat44@email.com"
                },
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "first":"Raymond",
                    "last":"Jefferson",
                    "email":"rayray007@email.com"
                }
            ],
            credentials: [
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "username":"johnee23",
                    "password":"abc123"
                },
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "username":"alexthegreat44",
                    "password":"alexandra"
                },
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "username":"rayray007",
                    "password":"agentray"
                }
            ],
            isAuthorized: false
        };
        this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }

    validate(e) {
        const username = e.target.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
        const password = e.target.querySelector('input[type="password"]').value;
        let authorized = false;
        {this.state.credentials.map(credential => {
            if(username === credential.username && password === credential.password) {
                authorized = true;
            }
            //alert(`Going through\nusername: ${credential.username}\npassword: ${credential.password}\nauthorized?: ${this.state.auth}\n\nYour input:\nusername: ${username}\npassword: ${password}`);
            alert(`${credential.username} === ${username}: ${credential.username === username}\n${credential.password} === ${password}: ${credential.password === password}\n${credential.username} === ${username} && ${credential.password} === ${password}: ${credential.username === username && credential.password === password}\nauthorized: ${authorized}`)
        })}
        alert(`authorized after done: ${authorized}`);


        // this.state.isAuthorized is not setting to true, even though the
        // authorized variable is already true. Confirmed through alert popups
        this.setState({
            isAuthorized: authorized,
        });
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        alert(`username: ${username}\npassword: ${password}\n\nisAuthorized: ${this.state.isAuthorized}\nauthorized: ${authorized}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                        <a href="#"><h2 class="navbar-brand">My Login Application</h2></a>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <div class="navbar-nav right">
                                <a href="#" className="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-item nav-link">Sign In</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8">

                            // ----- This is the form that submits on the validate function above ----------

                            <form action="#" onSubmit={this.validate}>
                                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                                <br />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">Your Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Your Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.validate}>Enter</button>
                            </form>

                            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-right vl  ">
                            <br />
                            <h1>Don't have an account?</h1>
                            <br />
                            <a href="#" className="btn btn-success" role="button">Sign up here!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4"></div>

                        <div className="col-md-6">

                            <br /><br />
                            <h1>Users</h1>
                            <ul>
                                {this.state.users.map(user =>
                                    <div>
                                        <li key={user.id}>Name: {user.first} {user.last}</li>
                                        <li key={user.id}>Email: {user.email}</li>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </ul>
                            <br /><br />
                            <h1>Credentials</h1>
                            <ul>
                                {this.state.credentials.map(cred =>
                                    <li key={cred.id}>{cred.username}: {cred.password}</li>
                                )}
                            </ul>
                            <br /><br />

                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light sticky-bottom">© Lockerroom Buzz: 2019-2020</nav>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

// Main.css
// ---------
// .right {
//   padding-left: 900px;
// }
//
// .title {
//   padding-left: 0px;
// }
//
// .vr {
//   border-right: 1px solid;
// }
//
// .navbar {
//   background-color: purple;
//   width: 100%;
// }
//
// .jumbotron {
//   width: 100%;
// }
//
// .center {
//   text-align: center;
//   margin-left: 25px;
// }
//
// .centralize {
//   padding-right: 20px;
// }
//
// .people {
//   width: 18rem;
// }
//
// .red {
//   color: red;
// }


export default Login;
```

Comment: Any error in browser console? try to log `authorized` right before `setState`, inside `validate` method, also try to update `isAuthorized` with hard-coded value and see if state get update

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` isn't synchronous, that's why:

```
this.setState({ isAuthorized: authorized });
console.log(this.state.isAuthorized) // here logs the value prior of the setState
```

If you want to log immediatly after the setState, pass a callback as the second parameter:

```
this.setState({ isAuthorized: authorized }, () => console.log(this.state.isAuthorized));
```

Comment: I noticed that the log is not printing even when called as a second parameter. It seems to me that the this.setState() function is not running. It skips over the this.setState() function.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the log is not printing even when called as a second parameter. It seems to me that the this.setState() function is not running. It skips over the this.setState() function within the validate() method.